# How to download files from archivists.xyz?

Tags: archive

How to download files like movies from archivists.xyz ?
I try to find solutions from different websites but cannot find the one that i was looking for!!
Can anyone tell how can i download movies and stuffs ??

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Join their group on Telegram.

Here's the telegram group's link https://t.me/TheArchivists

Read and confirm instructions and start accessing content

But at the present moment they're not accepting new members, you may try in a few days, weeks or months and see if you get lucky :)

Good luck!